# Show Serial number as roman letters in Telerik Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

need to display serial no as roman letters(i,ii) in telerik report .is there any in built functionality or is there any way to convert integer sl number to roman letters from the report side

Answer (score 0):

The number conversion is not supported in Telerik Reporting, but you can write a C# or VB method that will convert a number to roman numerals in a separate assembly. This assembly can be referenced in the configuration of your reporting application, allowing to call the conversion method via [UserFunctions](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/expressions-user-functions). In case the serial number comes from a database, it would probably be easier to write a server-side function that will convert it on the server and just use this value in your report. Here is an example of how to do that in MSSQL (never tested it though): [Convert Number to Roman Numerals in SQL Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/2089/convert-number-to-roman-numerals-in-sql-server.aspx).